# How to join the Stack Overflow development team?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to join the Stack Overflow development team?

Comment: Can you transfer data _to_ a 2400 bps modem simply by whistling? Are you able to take the sounds that another makes and convert it into ones and zeros (we're talking 7 even 1, none of that N81 hogwash)? If you can, they probably want to hear from you :) (in all seriousness, [yes, they're hiring](http://stackexchange.com/work-here) - scroll down near the bottom). [Being visible here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) will definitely increase your chances.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts96J7HhO28

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

See the [work here](https://stackexchange.com/work-here) link at the foot of every page.

However, I suspect that there is a *very* rigorous selection process...

Comment: LOL, I suppose that means OP already failed the hiring process. I'd avoid providing my username anywhere on the application if I were them. ;P

Comment: @deceze - I couldn't say - I'm not an employee...

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Looks at [the job adds](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange#jobs) of the Stack Exchange company at [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), apply for one of them and get hired.

Comment: And if they ask you one of those darned difficult Interview Questions, you know where to get help.